# Django foreign key field not updating with selected value from React Select dropdown

Tags: reactjs, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, react-select

I have a webpage in my issue tracker project that allows a project manager to assign a user to a project. I am using React Select to allow the manager to select a user from a dropdown. When they click the add user button, the selected value gets sent to the backend through an api call. I have an APIView called assignuser, which takes in the post request and updates the user foreign key field in my Project model.

Am I referencing the selected value wrong? I have tried sending selectedValue.value to my backend but it keeps on coming up as undefined. Keep in mind, obviously when you console.log selectedValue `{label: "...", value: "..."}` are both in selectedValue. This also applies to the SV in project.js that gets sent to manageusers.js. I'm just trying to reference value & send it to my APIView successfully and update the user of a particular project.

[project.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT8Ud.png)

[manageusers.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxPer.png)

**Django Backend**

```
class assignuser(APIView):
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.data.get('user')
            project_name = serializer.data.get('project_name')
            project = Project.objects.get(name=project_name)
            project.user = user
            project.save(update_fields=['user'])
            return Response(ProjectSerializer(project).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Incorrect Credentials")
```

**manageusers.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Grid, TextField, Button, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { FixedSizeList as List } from 'react-window';
import css from './style.css';
import Select from 'react-select';
import {useLocation} from "react-router";

const manageusers = () => {
  const [role, setRole] = useState([]);
  const location = useLocation();
  const [project_name, setProjectName] = useState();
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState()
  const rolelist = [];

  const handleChange = obj => {
      setSelectedValue(obj);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api/manageroles")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) =>{
        setRole(data)
    })
  }, [])

  const post = () => {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        user: selectedValue,
        project_name: project_name
      }),
    };
    fetch("/api/assignuser",requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((data) =>{
       
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      });
  }

  const Name = () => {
      return (
        <div>
            <Grid item xs={3}>
                <Typography component="h5" variant="h5">
                    {setProjectName(location.state.project_name)}
                </Typography>
            </Grid>  
        </div>
      )
    
  }

      return (
          <div>  
            {role.forEach(function(element) {
                rolelist.push({ label:element.username, value: element.username })
            })}
            <Select
                value={selectedValue}
                options={rolelist}
                onChange={handleChange}
                isOptionDisabled={option => option.isDisabled}
            />
            <div class="ex1">
                {role && role.map(roles => (
                        <Grid item xs={3}>
                            <Typography component="h5" variant="h5">
                                <h5> {roles.username} </h5>
                            </Typography>
                        </Grid>
                ))}
            </div>
            <div>
                <Button onClick={() => post()}> Add User</Button>
            </div>
            <Name/>
        </div>
      );
      
  }

export default manageusers;
```

**project.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Grid, TextField, Button, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Link,
    Route,
    Switch,
  } from 'react-router-dom';
import Select from 'react-select';

const project = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [description, setDescription] = useState();
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(null)
  const projectlist = [];
  
  const handleChange = obj => {
      setSelectedValue(obj);
  }

  const post = () => {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: name,  
        description: description,
      }),
    };
    fetch("/api/newProject",requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) =>{
       
      })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api/manageprojects")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) =>{
        setProjects(data)
    })
  }, [])

      return (
        <div>
           {projects.forEach(function(element) {
                projectlist.push({ value: element.name })
            })}
          <body>
            <Select 
                  value={selectedValue}
                  options={projectlist}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  isOptionDisabled={option => option.isDisabled}
              />
              <form action="#" method="POST">
                <TextField onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}> </TextField>
                <br>
                </br>
                <TextField onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}> </TextField>
                <br>
                </br>
                <Button onClick={() => post()}> Create New Project </Button>
              </form>
          </body>
          <div>
                {projects && projects.map(project => (
                    <Grid item xs={3}>
                        <Typography component="h5" variant="h5">
                            <h5> {project.name} </h5>
                            <h5> {project.description} </h5>
                        </Typography>
                    </Grid>
                ))}
          </div>
          <Link to={{
            pathname: '/manageusers',
            state: { 
                project_name: selectedValue
            }
          }}>Manage Users
          </Link>
        </div>
      );
  }
 


export default project;
```

**Project Model**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Users, null=True, blank=True, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
class assignuser(APIView):
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            project = serializer.validated_data.get("project_name")
            project.user = serializer.validated_data.get("user")
            project.save()
            return Response(ProjectSerializer(project).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Incorrect Credentials")
```

```
fetch("/api/assignuser",requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((data) =>{
         setRole([...role, data])    
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      });
```

or you can add new value without from backend for get new data,

why do I give this option, when you send data to the backend it will automatically be saved for that user and when the user reloads the value of the page that will come out remains the same

```
  const post = () => {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        user: selectedValue,
        project_name: project_name
      }),
    };
    fetch("/api/assignuser",requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((data) =>{
        setRole([...role, {label: project_name, value: project_name}])
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      });
  }
```

base.js

```
const Base = () => {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = React.useState()
  return (
    <div>
       <ManagerUser selectedValue={selectedValue} setProjectName={setSelectedValue}/>
       <Project selectedValue={selectedValue} setProjectName={setSelectedValue}/>
   </div>
  )
}
```

project.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Grid, TextField, Button, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Link,
    Route,
    Switch,
  } from 'react-router-dom';
import Select from 'react-select';

const project = (props) => {
  const {selectedValue,setSelectedValue} = props
  const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [description, setDescription] = useState();
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);
  const projectlist = [];
  
  const handleChange = obj => {
      setSelectedValue(obj);
  }

  const post = () => {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: name,  
        description: description,
      }),
    };
    fetch("/api/newProject",requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) =>{
       
      })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api/manageprojects")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) =>{
        setProjects(data)
    })
  }, [])

      return (
        <div>
           {projects.forEach(function(element) {
                projectlist.push({ value: element.name })
            })}
          <body>
            <Select 
                  value={selectedValue}
                  options={projectlist}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  isOptionDisabled={option => option.isDisabled}
              />
              <form action="#" method="POST">
                <TextField onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}> </TextField>
                <br>
                </br>
                <TextField onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}> </TextField>
                <br>
                </br>
                <Button onClick={() => post()}> Create New Project </Button>
              </form>
          </body>
          <div>
                {projects && projects.map(project => (
                    <Grid item xs={3}>
                        <Typography component="h5" variant="h5">
                            <h5> {project.name} </h5>
                            <h5> {project.description} </h5>
                        </Typography>
                    </Grid>
                ))}
          </div>
          <Link to={{
            pathname: '/manageusers',
            state: { 
                project_name: selectedValue
            }
          }}>Manage Users
          </Link>
        </div>
      );
  }
 


export default project;
```

Comment: what does validated_data do?

Comment: So I am trying to take the selected value from my frontend, send it to the assignuser, and set the foreign key named user in my project model with that selected value. That code you have just gets the last project in the queryset and returns it.

Comment: still no luck, I made an edit above to clarify what I was talking about

Comment: maybe you mean, when the user clicks button it will automatically appear in the dropdown?

Comment: maybe like this

Comment: No, so the dropdown is there with all of the users already. I made edits above again to show project.js. In the project webpage, the manager selects a project from the dropdown. They then click the manage users button, which then redirects to the manageusers page with the selected value. There is then another dropdown on manageusers for the manager to select a user to assign to the project. That then sends an api call to the backend, with both selected values, to filter for a project with that name. It then updates the user of that project with the user that they selected.

Comment: the problem is, selectedValue in both project.js and manageusers.js is {label: ..., value: ...}. I only need the value from that object.

Comment: maybe you can provide a picture as an example

Comment: you can this with props

Comment: maybe like this ?

Comment: What do you mean when the user clicks the add button, the selection of project.js manageruser.js will change

Comment: or not you can give simple example what you want

Comment: Provided the screenshots. Ignore the "Create new project" button